# Getting attribute from simple products of configurable products

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, ce-1.9.0.1, simple-product

After having to work on someone else's Magento webshop, I found a huge performance issue. The shop consists of configurable products. In the overview, an attribute from the simple products is shown. However, the person who made this before me, used `getUsedProducts` which caused enormous load times. I've been trying to optimise the script, but am still not satisfied.

The current code is the following:

```
            <?php 
            // First check if the product is configurable
            if($_product->isConfigurable()) {
                // get the necessary model
                $_helper2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                            ->setProduct($_product);
                $_subproducts = $_helper2
                                ->getUsedProductCollection()
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('color')
                                ->addFilterByRequiredOptions(); // the biggest speedbump

                // initialise our colours array
                $_colors = array();
                $_color_id = array();

                // look for attribute value of color in each associated product and assign to $_colours array
                foreach ($_subproducts as $_subproduct) {
                  // look for attribute value of color in each associated product and assign to $_colours array

                  $label = $_subproduct->getAttributeText('color');
                  $_colors[] = $label;

                  if (!isset($_color_id[$label])) {
                    $_color_id[$label] = $_subproduct->getData('color');
                  }
                }

                // remove dup's
                $_color_swatch = array_unique($_colors);

                echo '<ul class="color-swatch clearer">';

                foreach($_color_swatch as $_inner_option_id){
                    echo '<li class="color-li color-li-id-' . $_color_id[$_inner_option_id] . '"><div class="option-color color-id-' . $_color_id[$_inner_option_id] . '"><div class="option-color-desc">' . $_inner_option_id . '</div></div></li>';
                }

                echo '</ul>';
            }

            ?>
```

It get's the `color` attribute from each simple product, removes duplicates, and places one color swatch for each color. However, this still get's quite a big loading time, because it still loads too much information I think.

Could somebody point me in the right direction to create a better way of loading the attributes of the simple products?

---

Edit: IS there a better way of loading the attributes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have preferred to add  groupByAttribute for single list of  color

```
$ids=Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->getChildrenIds($parentId);


      $_subproducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addIdFilter ($ids)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('color')-> groupByAttribute('color');
```

Comment: Good call, that is even faster. Thank you!

Comment: Yep...nice idea with the grouping.

Answer (score 3):

Seams like you are doing it ok. I think you can also skip `->addFilterByRequiredOptions()` but not sure.
Here is an alternative. I don't know if it's better, but you can test and see the time difference.
The idea is to retrieve the child products collection like this:
Let's say that `$_product` is the configurable product.

```
$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($_product->getId()); //get the children ids through a simple query
$_subproducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $ids)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('color');
```

Comment: I had to change getting the `$ids` to `$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($_product->getId());`. Your way of getting the id's returned NULL in my case. Apart from that, it saves about 20% of the time. Thanks!

Comment: @SanderKoedood. Oups. I forgot to add something. I changed the answer. But I guess is similar to what you did.

Comment: Your edit gives me the following fatal error: `a:5:{i:0;s:66:"SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (((())))`

Comment: @SanderKoedood. Arrr...ignore it. Just go with what you got. I will change the answer.