# Need to get Simple Products with Configurable Option from Configurable Product

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product

I need to get details of all simple products associated with Configurable product along with product attributes

I used the existing magento functionality which returns empty value.

```
function getConfig($productIds) {
    $configurableData = array();
    $configProdCollctn = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $configProdCollctn->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=> $productIds))
                                   ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',
        array('eq'=> Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::TYPE_CODE));
    while ($product = $configProdCollctn->fetchItem()) {
        $prodAttrOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableOptions($product);
        foreach ($prodAttrOptions as $prodAttrOption) {
            $configurableData[$product->getId()] = array();
            foreach ($prodAttrOption as $optionValues) {
                $val = $optionValues['option_title'];
                $configurableData[$product->getId()][] = array(
                     $optionValues['sku'] =>  $optionValues['attribute_code']."=".$val
                );
            } 
        }
    }
    return ($configurableData);
}
```

This returns empty array.

for eg if config prod (A) has option of color and size. i need simple product A1,A2,A3 with color and size associated with options
     A1 = array(color => red,size => M)
     A2 = array(color => red,size => S)

Kindly Let me know how can I achieve this

Comment: I have updated with example if the question was unclear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution to the above requirment..

```
$product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($configId);
    #Check if the product has children
    if ($product->type_id == 'configurable') {
        $options = array();
        // Get any super_attribute settings we need
        $productAttributesOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableOptions($product);
        foreach ($productAttributesOptions as $productAttributeOption) {
                    $options[$product->getId()] = array();
                foreach ($productAttributeOption as $optionValues) {
                    $val = $this->trimValue($optionValues['option_title']);
                    $options[$product->getId()][] = array (
                        $optionValues['sku'] =>  $optionValues['attribute_code']."=".$val           
                    ) ;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Getting attribute from simple products of configurable products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24073/getting-attribute-from-simple-products-of-configurable-products)

```
$productId = 1; //config product id
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$configurable= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product);
$simpleCollection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();


foreach($simpleCollection as $simple){
   //$simple->getName();
}
```

See [Get simple products belonging to configurable products in magento](http://www.writeyourcode.com/get-simple-products-belonging-configurable-products-magento/)

Comment: The code which you suggested will return simple products.. i also require configurable option associated with that simple product.. for eg if config prod (A)  has option of color and size. i need simple product A1,A2,A3 with color and size associated with options
A1 = array(color => red,size => L)